# A function to close console window based on user input

Tags: c

I am writing a code for Dots and boxes game in C and I need a function that exit the game and close the window based on an input from the user for example when he presses the letter 'e' on keyboard the game should close  and I have no idea how to do that

Comment: your program is over the moment your `return` from `main`.

Comment: What do you mean by "window"?  Is the closing of that window an immediate consequence of your program terminating?  If so, just call `exit`.  If "close the window" means that you want your program to be manipulating objects in a window manager through some platform specific mechanism, you will have a lot more work to do.

Comment: In C, you normally get user input by the user entering input into a line and pressing the ENTER key. In your question, you state that you want your program to close "for example when he presses the letter 'e' on the keyboard." Does that mean that you need to receive the input before the user pressing the ENTER key? If so, then you will need to use platform-specific functionality. Otherwise, you can get input with [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) and check the string that the user entered, to see if the user entered `e`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are also predefined exit codes `EXIT_SUCCESS` and `EXIT_FAILURE`

```
#include <stdlib.h>

...
    exit(0);
...
```

e.g. `exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);`